# Capture traffic of android app on unknown port

Tags: android, proxy

I am using ProxyDroid to proxy everything to Charles Proxy. But by default Charles proxy (or any other similar programs like Fiddler, mitmproxy, etc..) only capture traffic on common ports such as 80, 8080, 443, 8443.

If an app is using a different port then the traffic would not show up in Charles proxy.

Is there anyway to know which port the app is using? Or any way around the issue?

Comment: android is based on linux so I'm guessing `lsof -i | grep "app"` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out Burp proxy?

https://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html

I always use Brup for any Android app, desktop app, website... and you don't even have to use ProxyDroid.

Connect you mobile phone and your laptop to the same LAN and configure the Burp proxy to start listening at your private ip. Then in android wifi options you can configure the proxy settings ip and port:

- Connect to WIFI network
- Settings->WIFI
- Long tap on connected network's name
- Modify network config-> Show advanced options
- Set proxy settings

After that configure Brup proxy options under the proxy tab to stop all requests and responses. After that you don't need to know the port that you app is using, all traffic from you smartphone will be shown in Brup.

https://support.portswigger.net/customer/en/portal/topics/718317-installing-and-configuring-burp/articles

Apart from that Burp have lots of features and plugins for fuzzing and other stuff, I don't know what are you trying to accomplish here but anyway this way should work for you!

Answer (score 0):

[Packet capture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture&hl=en) is much better, allows you to log raw network traffic from specific apps on all ports.

It's free.

Features:

- Capture network packets and record them.
- SSL decryption using man-in-the-middle technique.
- No root required.
- Easy to use.
- Show packet in either hex or text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

low rep so i'll post my comments here.

For `BurpSuite`: you'll have to modify the `hosts` file then on `Burp Suite`, listen on your target port via `transparent proxy`. You might have to enter all **65535** ports though.

For `Packet Capture`: sure it can **decrypt** SSL traffic. However, if `Wireshark` level `pcap` is what you are looking for, `Packet Capture` is still not enough.